# How to set the tablelayout android:layout_below programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have 2 table layout . I want to hide the second layout and move the third layout to second position.

I'm hiding the the second layout and but don't know how to move the third layout to second position

```
            TableLayout i=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table2);
    TableLayout i2=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table3);
    TableLayout i3=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table4);
    i.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    TableLayout i5=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table5);
             i5.// Now i want to add this layout below to table layout R.id.table1 (the first table layout in this section)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.removeView(id)` of the table layout then when u want use `view.addView(id)`

Comment: Thanks...
m confused about addview(id) . i was trying but htere is no such method/Parameter BELOW like in relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
i2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: i have done that part Sagar. I m asking that i want to move last table layout to the hidden layout place.

Comment: So you want to hide i,i2,i3 and take i5 to their place.?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like, as you said you are using RelativeLayout, so make a child LinearLayout with vertical orientation, then add all the table layouts you want to add.

Bow if you want to add a tableLayout at runtime at the first position, then do:

`linearLayout.removeAllViews();`

Then add the required TableLayout(here, i5) and after that add the remaining Layouts.

Edit: Your code:

```
TableLayout i=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table2);
TableLayout i2=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table3);
TableLayout i3=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table4);
i.setVisibility(View.GONE);
i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
TableLayout i5=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table5);
         i5.// Now i want to add this layout below to table layout R.id.table1 (the first table layout in this section)
```

Are you going right, as i think your code should look like:

```
TableLayout i=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);
TableLayout i2=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table2);
TableLayout i3=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table3);
i.setVisibility(View.GONE);
i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
TableLayout i5=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table5);
         i5.// Now i want to add this layout below to table layout R.id.table1 (the first table layout in this section)
```

I suggested this because of your comment section after `i5` in your above code.